# How to add an existing resource to stack using Python AWS-CDK?

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I tried deploying with the following definition but got `ExampleRole already exists` error.

```
from aws_cdk import aws_iam as iam
from aws_cdk import core

app = core.App()
stack = core.Stack(app, "MyStack")

existing_role = iam.Role(
    stack,
    id="ExampleRole",
    assumed_by=iam.AccountPrincipal(123456789),
    role_name="ExampleRole",
)
existing_role.apply_removal_policy(core.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN)

app.synth()
```

What is the correct procedure using CDK only?

Comment: Note: it's best practice to `from aws_cdk import core as cdk` and use the `cdk` variable instead of `core`.

Answer (score 2):

Root cause: you created stack, but you fetched role outside of it and therefore it is "orphan" and AWS CDK app cannot understand what it should do with it.

This problem should be addressed in three steps (bottom-up approach):

- project structure
- stack.py
- app.py
- deploy

I am using CDK v2.

0.1. **Project structure**

```
.
├── app.py
├── cdk.json
├── requirements.txt
├── .gitignore
└── stacks
    ├── stack.py
    └── __init__.py
```

This is a basic project structure which allows you to interact with AWS CDK.

0.2. **requirements.txt**

```
# CDK v2 update: npm install -g aws-cdk@next

aws-cdk-lib==2.0.0-rc.14
boto3
```

I added the content of requirements.txt just to be sure that we are on the same page. Also, it is good to update your AWS CDK npm to have the most recent version. This command should be run in cmd.

1. **stack.py**

```
import aws_cdk as cdk
from aws_cdk import aws_iam as _iam


class MyNewStack(cdk.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope, construct_id, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        # Fetch existing resources
        role = _iam.Role.from_role_arn(self, "my_existing_role",
                                       role_arn="role_arn_copied_from_webui_as-string", 
                                       mutable=False)
```

Here we create a stack where we list all our resources (new or already existing) using the CDK API. Link is given below to see all available options.

2. **app.py**

```
from stacks.Stack import *

# Initializing the CDK app
app = cdk.App()
env = cdk.Environment(account=os.getenv('CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT'), region=os.getenv('CDK_DEFAULT_REGION'))

# Stacks
MyNewStack(app, "stack-name-to-be-displayed-in-cloudformation", env=env)

# Required to get files updated in cdk.out
app.synth()
```

Here we initialize the CDK app and create instance of the class which we built previously.

3. **Deploy**

```
$cdk ls
$cdk synth
$cdk deploy stack-name-to-be-displayed-in-cloudformation
```

Before deployment, it is highly recommended to run `cdk ls`, `cdk synth`, `cdk diff` to see if everything is okay.

Please let me know in case I can help you more. Hope you find it useful. Cheers!

References to documentation and more:

1. Intro CDK: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/home.html
2. CDK API reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/modules.html
3. Better way to structure projects: https://www.sentiatechblog.com/aws-cdk-structure-components
4. CDK Patterns (real-life examples): https://cdkpatterns.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`iam.Role.from_role_arn()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_iam/Role.html#aws_cdk.aws_iam.Role.from_role_arn) to import an existing IAM role by ARN;

```py
existing_role = iam.Role.from_role_arn(
    stack,
    id="ExampleRole",
    role_arn="arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/......",
)
existing_role.apply_removal_policy(core.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN)
```

I've seen cases where functions like SQS `from_queue_arn()` and similar ones return a *read-only* reference to the resource, so you can't actually modify it with your CDK code; however, `from_role_arn` has a `mutable=True` parameter which says

> **mutable (`Optional`[`bool`])** – Whether the imported role can be modified by attaching policy resources to it. Default: true

So I'm not sure if it will work for you or not.

Comment: Thx, I will try!

Comment: It did not add the role to the stack unfortunately.

Comment: Also, I was not able to apply removal policy due to `Cannot apply RemovalPolicy: no child or not a CfnResource. Apply the removal policy on the CfnResource directly.`

Comment: Well, then I'd recommend opening an issue on their repo: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk.  The tool is pretty new and they make breaking changes _every week_, and they're pretty good about responding to issues, so you'll probably get support there.  If you do, remember to post back here for future readers ;)